# Why it is only reading first data in jmeter while putting load on websocket API. i am using WebSocket single read sampler to read data

Tags: websocket, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am passing data of 1 kb in file in jmeter while putting load on WebSocket API but it is only reading first passed data. I am using WebSocket single read sampler to read data.
in Jmeter it is only reading first data. How to solve this?
I tried by changing samplers but I am facing same type issue

Answer (score 0):

If the response doesn't fit into a single response you might want to put your request under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter) and use `${websocket.last_frame_final}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in the condition.

Source: [Fragmentation chapter](https://github.com/Luminis-Arnhem/jmeter-websocket-samplers#fragmentation) of the plugin repository:

> **Fragmentation**
>
> WebSocket messages may be fragmented into several frames. In such cases the first frame is an ordinary text or binary frame, but it will have the final bit cleared. The succeeding frames will be continuation frames (whether they are text or binary is inferred by the first frame) and the last continuation frame will have the final bit set. The plugin supports continuation frames, but as the plugin is frame-oriented, you'll have to read them yourself. In cases where the number of fragments is known beforehand, this is as easy as adding an extra WebSocketReadSampler for each continuation frame you expect. If the number of continuation frames is not known, you need to create a loop to read all the continuation frames. For this purpose, the plugin provides a new JMeter variable called `websocket.last_frame_final` that indicates whether the last frame read was final. This enables you to write a simple loop with a standard JMeter While Controller; use the expression `${__javaScript(! ${websocket.last_frame_final},)}` as condition. With a JMeter If Controller, the condition can be simplified to `! ${websocket.last_frame_final}` because that controller automatically interprets the condition as JavaScript. See the sample [Read continuation frames.jmx](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/samples/Read%20continuation%20frames.jmx) test plan for examples of using the While or the If controller to read continuation frames.
>
> If you are unsure whether continuation frames are sent by your server or how much, switch on debug logging: samplers reading a frame will log whether the received frame is a "normal" single frame, a non-final frame (i.e. 1st fragment), a continuation frame or a final continuation frame (last fragment).